# How to create Business Object from database in Stimulsoft report?

Tags: database, report, stimulsoft

I tried to create Business Object from database in stimulsoft report but stimulsoft just alow you to create Business Object manually.
Is any way to create Business Object from database automatically.
thank u for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It possible to register DataSet or DataTable as BUsiness Object using RegBusinessObject() method.